# Formatting var_dump output in lynx

Tags: php, debugging, bash, lynx

I'm debugging a php application via lynx (with -dump option) and I'm using a lot of debug variables. Unfortunatly, the output of var_dump is pretty messy, no matter if I dump it to the console or into a file. Is there any way to make it look better? I'm using bash.

Comment: You could install xDebug, that has a feature for pretty-printing var_dump output.

Comment: It just puts html tags around the output the make it look better in a real browser doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `print_r` over `var_dump`. I think that is the nicest you can get with PHP only.

Answer (score 0):

Install/activate xdebug. It makes your var_dump() output much prettier.

Comment: I'm not familiar with lynx but I guess not. xdebug makes the output prettier by using html fomatting.